# Place parsley error message under input field

Tags: html, css

How do I fix my parsley error message? I want to place it under the input field. I'm using bootstrap's input field.

This is my code:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="account_username" class="cols-sm-2 control-label">Username</label>
    <div class="cols-sm-10">
        <div class="input-group">
            <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-user fa" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="account_username" id="account_username" placeholder="admin.example" data-parsley-trigger="keyup" data-parsley-required="true"/>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: How about you just set the required field?

Comment: What do you mean? @Soban

Comment: I mean that inside your input field, try to remove the data parsley required and simply add `required`. Try that and tell me.

Comment: I tried it but the text is not fixed.

Comment: It should look something like this: https://imgur.com/a/aQEJXxf